# Regex has 3 slashes

Tags: regex, grep

I would like to remove all the lines, that has not at least 3 slashes.

eg. dataset:

```
/aafsaf/badba/asbsa
/asgas/
asgsagasg
asgasga
sagsgasg/agsg/vas/
/1/2/3/4
```

Should give back

```
/aafsaf/badba/asbsa
sagsgasg/agsg/vas/
/1/2/3/4
```

I know it's basic, I just can't find it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `grep -E` with this regex:

```
grep -E '([^/]*/){3}' file
/aafsaf/badba/asbsa
sagsgasg/agsg/vas/
/1/2/3/4
```

Regex `([^/]*/){3}` will find a line with at least 3 forward slashes.

Using `awk` it is even **shorter command**:

```
awk -F/ 'NF>3' file
/aafsaf/badba/asbsa
sagsgasg/agsg/vas/
/1/2/3/4
```

Comment: oops, after your edit, my answer is a duplicate. +1 yours. :)

Comment: Thanks, we probably thought about awk at the same time :)

Answer (score 0):

Through basic grep,

```
$ grep '/.*/.*/' file
/aafsaf/badba/asbsa
sagsgasg/agsg/vas/
/1/2/3/4
```